# How to add data to a table

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I created table1(example) and table2(attendanceinfo).
I inserted column1 and column2 value from table1 and I want to insert extra data in table2

```
con.Close()
con.Open()
Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("Insert into attendanceinfo(cid,cname) Select cid,cname From example Where cid=@ID", con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = TextBox1.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Using
```

Comment: And what happens when you run this code? Do you see error messages? What they say?

Comment: When you call ExecuteNonQuery, either an exception will be thrown or it will return the number of records affected. Which is it and, if the latter, what is the number?

Comment: I'm making a couple leaps here, but is the problem you want to know how to retrieve the id of the newly inserted record so that you can insert the records in a 1->many relation ship?